# How to import HTML as a string with ParcelJS

Tags: javascript, parcel, parceljs

I'd like to import HTML files as a string with ParcelJS, like this:

```js
import testHTML from './testHTML.html';

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', testHTML);
```

But the docs say:

> Importing HTML in JavaScript does not statically include the HTML strings, but the HTML files will dynamically be fetched using the Fetch API.

Is there any way to force the import as a string?

Answer (score 3):

- https://parceljs.org/languages/pug/

> ```
> import html from 'bundle-text:./index.pug';
> document.body.innerHTML = html;
> ```

### so, html is fine too

without any configurations

```
import html from 'bundle-text:./index.html';
document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

- https://parceljs.org/features/bundle-inlining/

### typescript fix `ts(2307)`

like "*.vue"

```
// index.d.ts
declare module 'bundle-text:*' {
    const s: string
    export default s
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following up after a few days - it didn't seem possible. [RollupJS](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/) had this ability though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rollup as module bundle, this plugin [rollup-plugin-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-html) will allow you to import a html file as string:

**rollup.config.js**

```
import htmlLoader from "rollup-plugin-html";

plugins: [
  ...
    htmlLoader({
      include: "**/*.html",
    }),
  ...
]
```

**Then:**

```
import testHTML from './testHTML.html';

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', testHTML);
```